# help with importing customers into magento 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, import

I have tried to import the attached listed using the example CSV sheet from Magento. But I keep getting an error that the headers are wrong. I attached the two files can you tell me what I am doing wrong. 
Thank you,
Ron

[image: error received]
[template used from magento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT4rW.jpg)

Comment: Remove the empty columns in your sheet and try again

Comment: Tried but no good now I have just the error of the ones showing after removing the others.

Comment: So can you try adding the missing ones at the end as columns and leave it as empty. I hope this might work for you